# Programmatically creating layout, using stack view and constraints not working

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I'm trying to create this layout programmatically in Swift.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NXRQbJ

The first rectangle is small. And the other 2 rectangles are the same size but bigger than the first rectangle.

Here is the entire View Controller. I am not using storyboard. All my code is in this view controller.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var stackView: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [smallRectangleView, bigRectangleView, bigRectangleView2])
        stackView.alignment = .fill
        stackView.distribution = .fillProportionally
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return stackView
    }()

    var smallRectangleView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .orange
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    var bigRectangleView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .green
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    var bigRectangleView2: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .purple
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        setupLayout()
        print(stackView.frame)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func setupLayout() {
        // Stack View
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        // Small Recntangle View
        let heightConstraint1 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: smallRectangleView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: bigRectangleView, attribute: .height, multiplier: 4.0, constant: 0.0)

        // Big Rectangle View
        let heightConstraint2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: bigRectangleView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: bigRectangleView2, attribute: .height, multiplier: 0.0, constant: 0.0)

        view.addConstraints([heightConstraint1, heightConstraint2])
    }
}
```

heightConstraint1 and heightConstraint2 is causing errors. I don't know why.

```
// Small Recntangle View
let heightConstraint1 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: smallRectangleView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: bigRectangleView, attribute: .height, multiplier: 4.0, constant: 0.0)

// Big Rectangle View
let heightConstraint2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: bigRectangleView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: bigRectangleView2, attribute: .height, multiplier: 0.0, constant: 0.0)

view.addConstraints([heightConstraint1, heightConstraint2])
```

When I run this app on the simulator nothing shows up. It's just a blank white screen. Also in the debugger there are issues with constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem seems to be the `stackView.distribution`.  I changed it from `.fillProportionally` to just `.fill`.  I suspect the issue was that the views were already relative to each other because of your constraints and that lead to conflicts.

Other changes I made, your `multiplier` in one of your constraints needs to be `0.25` instead of `4`, and in the second one the multiplier needs to be `1` instead of `0`.

I also used `NSLayoutConstraint.activate` to activate the last 2 constraints instead of adding them to the `view`.  In general, you want to activate constraints instead of adding them to views.  Let iOS figure out which views to add them to.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var stackView: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [smallRectangleView, bigRectangleView, bigRectangleView2])
        stackView.alignment = .fill
        stackView.distribution = .fill
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return stackView
    }()

    var smallRectangleView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .orange
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    var bigRectangleView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .green
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    var bigRectangleView2: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .purple
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        setupLayout()
        print(stackView.frame)
    }

    func setupLayout() {
        // Stack View
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        // Small Recntangle View
        let heightConstraint1 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: smallRectangleView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: bigRectangleView, attribute: .height, multiplier: 0.25, constant: 0.0)

        // Big Rectangle View
        let heightConstraint2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: bigRectangleView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: bigRectangleView2, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([heightConstraint1, heightConstraint2])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also continue to use iOS 9+ constraints instead of the older `NSLayoutConstraint(item:` without changing your original implementation:

```
func setupLayout() {
    let topViewHeight:CGFloat = 50.0
    let screenheight = view.bounds.height

    // Stack View
    view.addSubview(stackView)

    stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

    smallRectangleView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: topViewHeight).isActive = true

    bigRectangleView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: (screenheight - topViewHeight) / 2).isActive = true

    bigRectangleView2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: (screenheight - topViewHeight) / 2).isActive = true

}
```

[image: Debugger View]