# Multiline UILabel on navigation bar title view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uilabel

I have a custom UIView which has 2 `UILabel` (same width) and one `UIImageView` (known width of 44pt). Width sizes are given as an example, they can change but It is exact that `UILabels` should has same width and UIImage has a 44 point width. I want to add this view to `UINavigationBar`' `titleView` BUT `ImageView` should be in the **center** of navigation bar.

```
(60 width) UILabel---UIImageView (44 width) ---UILabel (60 width)
```

**I want** is that UILabels to have maximum two line and `adJustFontSizeToFitWidth` true. I'm giving specific width and height to title view but labels get two line but their font size doesn't change even they don't fit the view.

How I add titleView:

```
 navigationItem.titleView = myTitleView
    let widthOfItem: CGFloat = 30.0
    let pading: CGFloat = 40
    let aWidth: CGFloat = (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.width)! - CGFloat(1) * widthOfItem * 2.0 - pading

    myTitleView { (make) in
        make.width.equalTo(aWidth)
        make.height.equalTo(44)
    }
```

MyCustomView:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    let preferredWidth = (bounds.width / 2) - 56
    firstLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = preferredWidth
    secondLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = preferredWidth
}

private func setupViews() {

    addSubview(firstLabel)
    addSubview(myImageView)
    addSubview(secondLabel)

    firstLabel.font = .myFont(.bold, size: 36)
    firstLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    firstLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
    firstLabel.textColor = .textPrimary
    firstLabel.numberOfLines = 2
    firstLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    firstLabel.textAlignment = .right

    myImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    myImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    myImageView.layer.minificationFilter = .trilinear
    myImageView.layer.cornerRadius = currencyImageSize.height / 2

    secondLabel.font = . myFont(.bold, size: 36)
    secondLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    secondLabel.textColor = .textPrimary
    secondLabel.numberOfLines = 2
    secondLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    secondLabel.baselineAdjustment = .none
    secondLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
    secondLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    secondLabel.textAlignment = .left

    firstLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.leading.equalToSuperview()
        make.top.bottom.equalToSuperview()
        make.trailing.equalTo(myImageView.snp.leading).offset(-12)
    }

    myImageView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.height.equalToSuperview()
        make.width.equalTo(myImageView.snp.height)
        make.centerX.equalToSuperview()
    }
   secondLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.top.bottom.equalToSuperview()
        make.leading.equalTo(myImageView.snp.trailing).offset(12)
        make.trailing.equalToSuperview()
    }
}
```

Comment: Try putting them in a horizontal `UIStackView`.

Comment: The problem is that they have different size. I mean for example 20 width for image and 60, 60 for UILAbels. Can I do that in stack view?

Comment: Yes, each subview inside a stack view can have a different width.

Comment: It doesn't work. I can't get what I want. I edited my question

Comment: In your case you only need a constraint for the fixed width of the two labels, the stackview should take care of everything else. See for instance here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47949136/programmatically-creating-layout-using-stack-view-and-constraints-not-working

Comment: So when I give same width to UILabels and no width to imageView, should it work as expected which is imageView on the center and two labels left and right side of it?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't work sorry. There is a problem with using .lineBreakMode, .minimumScaleFactor, and .adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth at the same time. Can you please share code example?

Comment: Please note that `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` is *only intended for use with a single-line label*. See here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620546-adjustsfontsizetofitwidth

Comment: Aaa can't I do that both adjustFontSizeToFitWidth and two-line label?

Comment: That's what that links suggests. But there seem to be workarounds, see eg here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382976/multiline-uilabel-with-adjustsfontsizetofitwidth/7261514

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code will work?

```
class CustomNavClass: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup_view()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setup_view()
    }

    private func setup_view() {
        backgroundColor = .lightGray

        let image = UIImageView(image: .init())
        addSubview(image)

        image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        image.backgroundColor = .green

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            image.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
            image.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44),
            image.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44),

            image.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 3),
            image.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -3)
        ])

        let leftLabel = UILabel()
        leftLabel.text = "Label label left long label will go here, naturally"
        leftLabel.numberOfLines = 2
        leftLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        leftLabel.backgroundColor = .red

        addSubview(leftLabel)

        leftLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            leftLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            leftLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            leftLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: image.leadingAnchor, constant: -10)
        ])

        let rightLabel = UILabel()
        rightLabel.text = "Label label right long label will go here, naturally"
        rightLabel.numberOfLines = 2
        rightLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        rightLabel.backgroundColor = .blue

        addSubview(rightLabel)

        rightLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            rightLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            rightLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            rightLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: image.trailingAnchor, constant: 10)
        ])
    }
}
```

The code **does not** use a `UIStackView` as its limited to its function (specifically, only one `UIView` can be stretched out on `.fill` `distribution` property.

This instead creates layout constraints:

1. `UIImageView` that is pegged at the `center`(with a 3 top and bottom constraint, optional, you can use centerY constraint or the like).
2. Leading `UILabel` is pegged to leading edge and trailing edge with `UIImageView`'s leading edge.
3. Trailing `UILabel` is pegged to trailing edge and leading edge with `UIImageView`'s trailing edge.

[image]

Comment: The problem is that there is a left bar button item on navigation bar so can you please show me how you center image in this scenario?

Comment: Should the left bar button item be shown alongside the left label? I'm actually expecting this though the methodology to do left bar button item is hacky. And it requires the view to be removed from `titleView` and placed inside `UINavigationBar`'s subview.

Comment: Yea yea. It is in navigation bar NOT in title view. It is a usual back button but as you know when you have some item on the left side title views width is total (screen width - bar button item) so that centering something is hacky

Comment: Oki! I shall make my edits with those requirements.

Comment: I tested your code It is working when u set text earlier and with  default font but when I make font size 36PT bold and set text after view is created, It is not working. Left label even goes beyond title views bounds.

Comment: It won't. Since the requested font size is too big even with font size adjustments.

Comment: and also It breaks when I add linebreakMode of byWordWrap

Comment: I tried increasing the text size and adding byWordWrap it works on my end. https://imgur.com/a/T4cZ0SY

Comment: Also, I was able to center the image view I deferred the constraint construction for centerX after setting the titleView property!

Comment: In your screenshot, labels frame goes beyond titleView. It should decrease the font size that's why we add adjustFontSizeToFitWidth right?

Comment: It should, but I forgot to add constraints to the top and bottom edges of the label. I added that and the text just got truncated.

Comment: Yes that was the problem actually. What I'm looking for the answer for :)

Comment: Ah, after experimenting with .lineBreakMode, .minimumScaleFactor, and .adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth. I think lineBreakMode and adjustFontSizeToFitWidth is mutually exclusive, as iOS will not know where to peg the actual width of the UILabel.

Comment: I think It is something to do with contentHuggingPriority

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214116/discussion-between-rantingmong-and-emre-onder).